# Which students have a final of over 90 in more than one course in 2006?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access-2010

I have a table of students and the grades they get during a certain year and a certain course. I need to write a query that will return the studentID, courseID, and finalGrade for students who made over a 90 in multiple courses. This is what I have so far. I can output a list of students, the course they took and their final grade but I don't know how to narrow the list to students whose ID would appear more than once in this list if they made > 90 in two or more courses.

```
SELECT GRADES.StudentID, GRADES.CourseID, GRADES.Final, Count(*)
FROM GRADES
GROUP BY GRADES.StudentID, GRADES.CourseID, GRADES.Final, GRADES.Year
HAVING (((GRADES.Final)>90) AND ((Count(*))>1) AND ((GRADES.Year)=2006));
```

Comment: Are you using Postgres or MS Access?  They are very different databases.

Comment: Honestly both. I've been executing queries in the design view of Access then pasting them into postgres and making the necessary syntax edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds simple. This is standard SQL, don't know if Access supports it:

```
SELECT studentid, courseid, final
FROM (SELECT studentid, courseid, final,
             COUNT (*) FILTER (WHERE final > 90)
                       OVER (PARTITION BY studentid)
                AS num_courses_over_90
      FROM grades
      WHERE year = 2006
     ) AS q
WHERE num_courses_over_90 > 1;
```

I am not sure whether you want *all* courses for these students listed in the final result or only the courses where they score over 90. If it is the latter, add the following in the end:

```
AND final > 90
```